# My system crashes when trying to apply a function to a pandas dataframe via vectorizing a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have created a process in which I am matching records in the pandas dataframe via names. These names are not necessarily standardized by format, spelling, or anything like that, so this matching is accomplished through a fuzzy matching approach.

Essentially I am trying to take every record's name field, and match those to all other associated records. After some research, it was apparent that passing the matching function though a vectorized numpy array would be the faster approach. However, running my code on even 100 records crashes my system. It works on 1 however. I am not yet knowledgeable enough to know about memory constraints, but my fear is that the memory requirements on this function are being overloaded.

The name field values are a string. I am trying to write a list of matching records to a new column. The "match_name" call is to a separate function that works by using a tuple of the name's elements and creating a phonetic code for the combinations of those elemental names. It then accesses a dictionary that has already been populated with every records phonetic code combinations and returns the unique IDs for where those codes match. This list of record IDs is what I am trying to write into the new field.

There are a few hundred thousand records I am trying to test this on right now.

NOTE: the initial few lines are simply creating the standardized name tuple. They refence some keyword dictionaries to drop unique characters and expand abbreviated names.

````
def test(in_name):
    name=str(table["name_field"]).upper()
    for clean in NameCleaner:
        name=name.replace(clean ,'')            
    for expand in NamesExpander:
        name = name.replace(expand, NamesExpander[expand])
    name =  re.sub(r"\b[a-zA-Z]\b", "", name)
    name = (normalize_unicode_to_ascii(name)).strip()
    tp = tuple(name.split(" "))
    match_list = match_name(tp)
    
    return match_list

def main(df):
    df["Matches"] = [test(df["name_field"].values)]```
````

Comment: Do you get an error message when it crashes?

Comment: No, my whole computer crashes and I have to restart. That's I am thinking its a memory issue or something along those lines. Currently I am running this with an I5 processor and 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: I came across something that suggested making sure each iteration of the function dropped the previous data to keep memory requirements low. But I am not sure how to ensure that is happening here.

Comment: Using up all your system memory won't crash your system, the operating system will first attempt to move memory blocks to disk (swap under Linux, pagefile for Windows) until some limit and then start to kill programs. Hard crashes are frequently bad hardware or drivers.

Comment: If your computer slows down to a crawl (not crashed, but perhaps unusable), it may be that you have a slow disk and the operating system is swapping, which destroys the performance (disk IO is thousands of times slower than memory). If that's the case, disabling swap/pagefile may help the program make better use of the real memory (some operations check available memory, but the operating system will tell it there is more because it's offering the very slow disk space) or show that it's really filling it all (out of memory error).

Comment: compile the re expression before using it, tmp = re.compile(r"\b[a-zA-Z]\b")  name =  re.sub(tmp, "", name)